# Getting value out of JavaScript lookup table

Tags: javascript

I have made a lookup table whose keys are names of lists a user makes. I have stored the values for each list in a function and am having a hard time getting the values out. How can I get a certain value within list key?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pgpx28r9/

What I am trying:

```
var listLookupTable = {
    '1': function(){
      return {
        'comments': 'a comment',
        isPrivate:true,
        revealAmazingStuff:false,
        receiveFreeStuff:false,
        receiveEmails:true,
      }
  },
  'two': function(){
    return {
        comments: 'cool',
        isPrivate:false,
        revealAmazingStuff:false,
        receiveFreeStuff:true,
        receiveEmails:true,
      }
   },
  'new stuff': function(){
      return {
        comments: 'another one',
        isPrivate:true,
        revealAmazingStuff:true,
        receiveFreeStuff:true,
        receiveEmails:true,
      }
  },
}

console.log(listLookupTable['1']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing/returning a function. For getting the values, you have to call the function first and then use a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), like

```
listLookupTable['1']().comments
//    function call ^^ 
//                    ^^^^^^^^^ property accessor
```

or

```
listLookupTable['1']()['comments']
//    function call ^^ 
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ property accessor
```

For the version witch returns a function, I suggest to store the result of function call in a variable, because you need only one call for getting the object:

```
one = listLookupTable['1']();
alert(one.comment + one.isPrivate);
```

If you don't like the function call, or do not have active content, you can use an object literal with objects instead of functions inside:

```js
var listLookupTable = {
    '1': {
        'comments': 'a comment',
        isPrivate: true,
        revealAmazingStuff: false,
        receiveFreeStuff: false,
        receiveEmails: true,
    },
    'two': {
        comments: 'cool',
        isPrivate: false,
        revealAmazingStuff: false,
        receiveFreeStuff: true,
        receiveEmails: true,
    },
    'new stuff': {
        comments: 'another one',
        isPrivate: true,
        revealAmazingStuff: true,
        receiveFreeStuff: true,
        receiveEmails: true,
    },
};

document.write(listLookupTable['1'].comments);
```